# What happens with the constraints after rotating the view?

Tags: java, android, android-constraintlayout

What happens with the constraints after rotating the view?
I'm trying to fit container(question_container) to center of screen, but this container must be able to rotate. After rotating constraints is not work.

Screen before rotating:

[image]

Screen after rotating:

[image]

What happens after rotating -90 degree?

Did "START" point become "BOTTOM" point and "TOP" point become "START"?

That's how I set constraints:

```
        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/question_container"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
            android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
            android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
            android:orientation="vertical"
            android:rotation="@{viewModel.currentRotationValue}"
            android:visibility="@{viewModel.started &amp;&amp; !viewModel.needShowAnswer ? View.VISIBLE : View.INVISIBLE}"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/player_card_0"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@+id/player_card_2"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/player_card_5"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/player_card_4">
```

Comment: Left is always START.

Comment: Thanks! If constraints are set correctly then problem in my customView. (

Comment: No, problem isn't in my CustomView, I replaced the playerCards on Buttons, but after rotating TOP & BOTTOM constraints is not works.